# Write a function to iterate and pluck an inner array's objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, lodash

**How could I use vanilla js or lodash to return Scene.data[i].trends into a one `newArr`**

### Output should look like this:

```
var  newArr = superFunction();
console.log(newArr);
=> [{id:100},{id:101},{id:200},{id:201}]
```

**Dataset:**

```
Scenes.data = [
  {
    id: 0,
    trends: [
      {
        id: 100,

      },
      {
        id: 101,

      }]
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    trends: [
      {
        id: 200,              
      },
      {
        id: 201,
      }]
  }]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With lodash you can use pluck and flattern:

```
var result = _(scenes).pluck('trends').flattern().value();
```

Or maybe reduce (plain js):

```
var result = scenes.reduce(function(prev, curr) {
  return prev.concat(curr.trends);
}, []);
```

Comment: Hey do you have any opinions on dystroy answer vs yours? His vanillajs is slightly different and I cannot tell why or which one is better?

Comment: After a bit of research it seems like the difference between dystory and yours is map vs reduce. Which I don't know if there a noticeable difference in preformance? Seems that the right answer is the most readable answer yeah? Omri approach seems to work just fine also it is pretty readable. However, it takes a lot of space? I dont know which to choose as the best answer.

Comment: You're just seems like the most flexible and easy to read.  If you have any comments on benefits, costs, cons that would be super helpful

Answer (score 2):

You can do this :

```
var newArr = [].concat.apply([], Scenes.data.map(function(v){ return v.trends }));
```

[Demonstration](http://jsbin.com/futucidebu/1/)

Comment: Hey do you have any opinions on jose answer vs yours? His vanillajs is slightly different and I cannot tell why or which one is better?

Comment: After a bit of research it seems like the difference between jose and yours is map vs reduce.  Which I don't know if there a noticable difference?  Seems that the right answer is the most readable answer yeah?  Omri approach seems to work just fine also it is pretty readable.  However, it takes a lot of space? I dont know which to choose as the best answer.

Comment: This version seems faster as it loops the main array once and then concatenates them once, while the other one does a concatenation as many times as `newArr.length`, but you can use jsperf to actually prove this. You could wrap this in a `pluck(newArray, 'trends')` function and call it a day readability-wise.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
var newArr = [];

Scenes.data.forEach(function(x) {
    x.trends.forEach(function(trend) {
        var obj = {};
        for(var key in trend) {
            if (trend.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                obj["" + key + ""] = trend[key];
            }
        }
        newArr.push(obj);
    });
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/seyenaz/uce6d97q/3/)

Comment: What if there are more keys than id?

Comment: @MatthewHarwood That's all you said you needed, right? What else is there? Notice we're iterating over all the objects in the array, all the trends and just getting the ID for the output.

Comment: I wanted to return the whole object.  for the keys are custom per object. e.g
{id: 101, stuff: 'im some stuff'}, {id: 103, thing: 'im a thing'}

Comment: If you look at Jose or Dystroy answer their answer are a bit more versatile and therefore, work.  But honestly I can only read your answer.  lol

Comment: @MatthewHarwood Hehe :) I'd be happy to modify it if I understood a little bit better where you take the other properties from, like "stuff/thing" that you wrote. Are they from `trends` ?

Comment: Basically i want all object from trends into one array.